# Choosing edges to disconnect graph

Tags: graphs, network-analysis

I have an undirected simple graph and an integer x.
My goal is to remove x edges from the graph so the largest connected component of the graph after the removal will be minimal.

I tried to think how to solve this problem, and i thought maybe using Girvan-Newman algorithm for removing edges with highest Betweenness. Works but very time consuming (running betweenness each round).

Any suggestions or other ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: This certainly looks like an NP-complete problem, swims like an NP-complete problem and quacks like an NP-complete problem...

Comment: @TomvanderZanden : ​ It seems far more likely to me that it would be [F](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp)P[$^{||}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pparnp)$^{\text{F}}$[$^{\text{NP}}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp)-complete than NP-complete. ​ ​ ​ (It's also obviously in [W$[\hspace{-0.03 in}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:W#wp)P][O](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#npo).) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I can't read your comment because your manual negative spacing makes the symbols collide. How many times do we have to ask you to **STOP DOING THAT**?

Comment: Try a reduction from the *balanced partition* problem: given a set of an even number of positive integers, can it be partitioned into two sets of equal sizes and equal sums?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : ​ That can be solved by dynamic programming, so it'll be in P for unary inputs. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Right, that actually doesn't work.

Comment: You can take a look at the NP hardness of minimum bisection for inspiration (or even try a reduction).